# I get FileNotFoundException and IllegalArgumentException when running my web application in tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat7

I get  the following Exceptions while running my web application in tomcat server:
1:
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path {myWorkspace}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\bin/keystore due to {myWorkspace}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\bin\keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: {myWorkspace}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\bin\keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:291)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManager..........................
2:
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8444"]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: {myWorkspace}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\bin\keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:385)...........................
3:
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base {myWorkspace}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps{workspcae name} does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5002)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5182)

Answer (score 0):

Your application requires a file(A keystore in your case) that is not present inside the war file or maybe you're referring to a folder where you need to copy the .jks file.

Make sure to check the path that you are providing for the keystore(.jks) file is correct.

Comment: I'm new to keystore so correct me if I'm wrong, I could not find any .jks files anywhere, so how could I add them, and what is the actual use of keystore here?

Comment: A keystore file basically contains private keys or certificates for your application. Judgin by the logs, it probably seems a war file that you're trying to deploy (I might be wrong here), so in that case goto the tomcat/conf folder and under server.xml, look if there is any mention of the jks file.

Comment: Else you can look in the code for the same,
Use CTRL+H and search for "jks"
This is for eclipse by the way.